# Slice string between specific characters in GET parameters?

Tags: javascript, string, iframe, slice

I need to remove certain GET parameters from an `iframe` src attribute that is being dynamically generated by a BrightCove video player. Namely `width` and `height`, as I want the width and height of the parent to trump. As I don't know how many characters the width and height will be, I assume I will need a `.slice()` method that looks for separators. However, I can't figure out how to do this, as all the other parameters are needed.

```
<iframe src="http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/htmlFederated?&amp;width=590.7692307692307&amp;height=332.307692307&amp;flashID=myExperience&amp;playerID=168451210200&amp;etc, etc, etc"></iframe>
```

Any ideas?

Many thanks,
James

Comment: First of all, you need to learn the difference between POST and GET …

Comment: damn, my bad. updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by searching for substrings before using slice. However you could use a regular expression instead:

```
var regex = /width=([\d\.]*).*height=([\d\.]*)/
var dimensions = regex.exec(srcString);
```

This expression searches for "width" and "height" and selects any digit or dot after them in dimensions[1] and dimensions[2].